# use $scope of controller in filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I declare $scope.something in my controller like

```
app.controller('MainControl', function($scope){
$scope.something = 1;
});
```

then how can I access it in my filter scope? like

```
app.filter("myCustomFilter", function () {
// here
});
```

obviously it doesn't work if I just $scope.something there.

Comment: {{*** | somefilter:this}} used to work but I don't think it does anymore, you can't pass a scope directly to a filter you must do a work around like @JoseM's solution

Comment: You can't, thats not what filters are for.

Comment: Oddly, It still works http://jsbin.com/miqazola/1/

Comment: Why you do need to do this? I suggest you re-evaluate what you are trying to achieve as you should never expose the scope to a filter.

Comment: Oddly, i tried in my case but it doesn't work, how u do that?

Comment: Oh wait, I don't want to return but set something..

Comment: http://jsbin.com/miqazola/1/

Comment: @IssamZoli no I mean it's a must to use a return function? because myCustom filter already return something else

Comment: with "this" you pass controller's $scope in the 2nd argument to the filter, do whatever what you want with it, but still not a clean way I still think you better use a scope method or something else or tell us your goal and we can find a better solution.

Comment: The first return must return the function which is the real filter. In the second return you return what you want which will be printed

Comment: @IssamZoli this gave me error still http://jsbin.com/juxebewu/1/edit?html,output

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50901/discussion-between-issam-zoli-and-noob)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a chat here is the working solution http://jsbin.com/juxebewu/4/edit

```
<div ng-controller="sCtr">
    <ul>
      <li>{{aa | friends:this}}</li></ul>{{showItem}}
      <p ng-show="showItem">click</p>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
```

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);
var targetOfFriendTasks = 1;
var user = [];
user[0]= {uId: 1};

app.filter("friends", function () {
   return function (input, s) {
       var output = [];
       for (var i in input) {            
           if (input[i].name.length >= 1 && input[i].uId == targetOfFriendTasks) {      
               output.push(input[i]);
           }
       }

       if (targetOfFriendTasks != user[0].uId) {
           return output;
       } else {
            s.showItem = true;
       }

   };
});

app.controller('sCtr', function ($scope) {

  $scope.aa = [{name:"lorem", uId:1}, {name:"ipsum", uId:2}];
    $scope.showItem = false;

});
```

Comment: [Link-only answers are discouraged on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65277/are-link-only-answers-poor-practice). Please copy the code into your answer.